# How to generate a DAG for the given epoch with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, testing, dag

I need to run some integration tests that include block sealing. I would like to separate the process of DAG generation from the tests themselves. Is it possible to pregenerate the given DAG with geth?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript function [miner.makeDAG()](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#minermakedag) can be used to generated a DAG for specified block number.

```
geth --exec "miner.makeDAG(0)" console
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the updated documentation, since this is the first link when searching.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining#ethash-dag